# How to observe if a property doesn't change for a specific interval in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, rx-swift

I want to observe `speed` property of CLLocation updates and trigger an event if the speed doesn't change for 10 seconds and if the speed changes reset the timer. Could only come up with this much code till now.

```
let location: Observable<CLLocation>

location.subscribe(onNext: { (coordinates) in
    print(coordinates)
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I assume we could use `debounce` or `throttle` but not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// will emit element when speed doesn't change for 10 seconds
let lastLocation = location
    .distinctUntilChanged { $0.speed == $1.speed }
    .debounce(.seconds(10), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) 

Observable.merge(location, lastLocation)
    .subscribe(onNext: { coordinates in
        print(coordinates)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
What I understand from it is that if a location doesn't change, but in my case, I'm constantly getting coordinate updates.
What I want to check is that has the value of location changed or not for 10 seconds.

Comment: @DaniyalRaza Then you should add the distinctUntilChanged operator. I have edited the answer